# Display content of html to mail in jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins

[image]

Above is the snapshot where i'm adding html file to send mail.

And expected : [image: [![enter image description he]

but got html content in mail.

Is there any way to load html in mail.

Comment: Change the content type to text/html or html only. Then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First change the content type to text/html.
   [image]
2. And use variable in HTML in the [correct way](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).